# iterate over lua table is not working

Tags: scripting, lua, luagl

I have the following lua table :

> t = {name="sandy", age="22", major="computerScience"}

I want to iterate over it, both methods below do NOT work

Method 1

> function printAssociateTable(t)  print("before the loop")    for i,v
>   in ipairs(t) do
>       print(v)    end end

Method 2

> function printAssociateTable2(t)  print("before the loop")    for k in
>   ipairs(t) do
>       print("before the loop")
>       print(k.. " is " ..t.k)    end end

when I call either methods, they print "before the loop". so the problem the program is not entering the loop !

i tried to manually access the table, if i do this :

> return t.name 
>    => gives sandy
>
> return t[name]
>    =>  gives **nil**
>
> return t["name"]
>     =>  gives sandy !

how can i iterate over my table ? kindly note that both methods work well with a simple array like this

> a={"a","b","c","d"}

but i want it to work on my associative array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ipairs` iterator selects only the array elements with *integer* keys. To iterate over all keys you require `pairs`, like this:

```
function printAssociateTable(t)
  print("before the loop")
  for i,v in pairs(t) do
    print(v)
  end
end
```